# Java Histogram Equalisation - Can't get Pixel from Image Raster

Tags: java, image, image-processing, histogram, normalization

I have been business a histogram equalisation method. I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015287/histogram-equalization-using-java) as a foundation to build on. However I cannot get this code to run and Google isn't too helpful in helping me find the issue. I pass in a JPG BufferedImage object. I first display the image so I see what I'm working with and then process it. However it ALWAYS fails on the line int `valueBefore=img.getRaster().getPixel(x, y,iarray)[0];` and I'm not sure why. The error I get is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` but I cannot see *why* it gives this error, the picture is there and filled with pixels!

```
public BufferedImage hisrogramNormatlisation(BufferedImage img) {
        // To view image we're working on
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        int width =img.getWidth();
        int height =img.getHeight();
        int anzpixel= width*height;
        int[] histogram = new int[255];
        int[] iarray = new int[1];
        int i =0;

        // Create histogram
        for (int x = 50; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 50; y < height; y++) {
                int valueBefore=img.getRaster().getPixel(x, y,iarray)[0];
                histogram[valueBefore]++;
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }

         int sum = 0;

         float[] lut = new float[anzpixel];
         for ( i=0; i < 255; ++i )
         {
             sum += histogram[i];
             lut[i] = sum * 255 / anzpixel;
         }

         i=0;
         for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
             for (int y = 1; y < height; y++) {
                 int valueBefore=img.getRaster().getPixel(x, y,iarray)[0];
                 int valueAfter= (int) lut[valueBefore];
                 iarray[0]=valueAfter;
                  img.getRaster().setPixel(x, y, iarray); 
                  i=i+1;
             }
         }
         return img;
    }
```

Error description:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.getPixel(ComponentSampleModel.java:n)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.getPixel(Raster.java:n)
    at MainApp.hisrogramNormatlisation(MainApp.java: * line described *)
    at MainApp.picture(MainApp.java:n)
    at MainApp.<init>(Main.java:n)
    at MainApp.main(Main.java:n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace you posted says your out of range index is 1.
The exception isn't thrown where you think it is.
getPixel(int x, int y, int[] iarray) fills iarray with the intensity values of the pixel. If you are using an rgb image, there will be at least three intensity values for each channel, if you are using rgb with alpha there will be 4 intensity values. Your iarray is just of size 1, so when raster wants to access further elements to store the additional values an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.
Increase the size of iarray and the exception will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use getPixel(), but getSample().

So your code would be: `final int valueBefore = img.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 0) ;` or even `histogram[img.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 0)]++ ;`

Btw, you may want to check the image type first in order to determine the number of channels/bands and do this process for each channel.